# jquery autocomplete on multiple inputs fields not filtering results

Tags: jquery, symfony

In my symfony (v2) application, i have a code that display orders details in table.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed .zebra-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="20">#</th>
<th>Libelle</th>
<th width="100">Account number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

{% for item in entity.elements %}
<tr>
<td> {{loop.index}}</td>
<td> {{item.libelle}}</td>
<td><input type="text" name="namecpte[]" class="cpte" id="idcpte_{{loop.index}}"></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
</table>
```

and I must add a account number's in Account number input by autocomplete (see the code above the line):

```
<td><input type="text" name="namecpte[]" class="cpte" id="idcpte_{{loop.index}}"></td>
```

here is my autocomplete code:

```
$('.cpte').on("focus", function(){
var idInput = $(this).attr('id')
var a='#'+idInput;
b = $(a);
b.autocomplete({
  source : function(requete, reponse){
    var id =  b.val();
    var DATA = 'id=' + id;
        $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url : "{{ path('cpte_numero') }}",
           dataType : 'json',
           data : DATA, 
           success : function(donnee){
            reponse($.map(donnee, function(objet){
            return objet; 
            }));
           }
         });
       }
     });
    });
```

the problem is when i typing in account number input ,the autocomplete display (all accounts,there are 789 accounts) but results is not filtered.
For example when i typing

> *45*

autocomplete must returns ( 2 accounts)

> *4581* 
>   *4588*

but it returns 789 accounts

how to solve it? thank in advance

PS : I apologize for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method that your cpte_numero route points to, you need to get the data posted from your AJAX call, then filter the results based on what is posted to that controller.

E.g. something like:

```
public function cpteNumeroAction(Request $request) {

    // $data = $request->request->all(); var_dump($data); // you can use this for debugging
    $accountPartialId = $request->request->get('id'); // assuming your post data is this format

    // then based on account partial id you can filter E.g.
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $accountIds = $qb->select('a.accountNumber')
        ->from('YourBundle:Account', 'a')
        ->where($qb->expr()->like('a.accountNumber', ':comparison'))
        ->setParameter('comparison', $accountPartialId . '%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    // maybe you need to format your data a little more here

    return new JsonResponse($accountIds); // maybe you have JSON, maybe some other format
}
```

This is just an approach/example to get you started.

Comment: ,thanks, but I already do the same thing as you say and autocomplete return all  accountNumber (it not filtered)